# What prevents me from jumping to any absolute address using ASM?

Tags: assembly, operating-system

What prevents me from executing just `jmp @9274592` even if it's outside of my program's limits? Don't I write directly into the CPU? What exactly, in the operating system I presume, prevents the command from being executed?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from jumping into a random point in the address space. But once the processor tries to run code from their, a fault occurs because the address space isn't marked as executable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That depends on your operating system, and on your hardware.  On modern systems, **the operating system controls hardware-provided memory protection**.

---

In typical microprocessors of the 1980s, nothing prevents access (including execution) anywhere in the memory space - and erroneous code will likely crash the machine.  This is also true of early single-user machines with cooperative multitasking, such as DOS and the original Mac.

In modern workstation-class machines, the processor includes a [Memory Management Unit (MMU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit), which controls access to memory.  The most widely-used mechanism is [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), with per-page permission bits.  Each process has its own virtual address space.

---

Operating systems such as Unix or Linux write to the MMU to specify which pages can be read/written/executed by the current process (writing to MMU is a privileged operation that can't be done by the process itself).

A jump to a location in a page without execute permission will cause a processor trap; this switches the processor to privileged mode and enters the kernel, which can then decide what to do.  Usually, this means sending a `SIGSEGV` signal to the process (and this is why you might see an error message like `Segmentation fault` when your program crashes).

When several user processes are running simultaneously in a [time-sliced environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice), it is the kernel's job to switch the MMU contents at every context switch.  The cost of [invalidating the TLB on an address-space switch (and the resulting TLB misses)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer#Address_space_switch) can constitute the major overhead in time-shared systems.

Comment: The MMU isn't actual a separate thing in modern CPUs; it's integral to each CPU core.  In x86, the page tables just live in normal RAM, and the kernel sets CR3 (with a [mov to control register instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV-1.html)) to point to the top-level page directory data structure.  Changes to the page tables (like after mmap/munmap) only require selective flushing of the special-purpose translation cache (TLB), e.g. using an `invlpg` instruction.  Anyway, I just found it weird to speak of "programming the MMU" like it was separate like a GPU or something.

Comment: But yes: **TL:DR summary of this answer**: memory protection, usually in the form of virtual memory.  It's done by the OS with hardware support.

Comment: I made some edits so your answer doesn't sound like it's describing a "modern" 1985 Sun workstation with a 68020 and a separate MMU.  (hah, I just googled, and I guessed [the right year and CPU for a Sun-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun-3)).  Any CPU with virtual addressing and cache will have the MMU basically integrated into the core (or each core if more than one), because caches are normally physically tagged, and thus need address-translation before they can even check the tags.  Some designs use virtually tagged L1 cache to avoid the need for a really high speed TLB, but still.

Comment: Great edit - thanks!  It seems I'm starting to show my age...  :-/

Comment: If you're curious, the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has some good links to hardware-overview stuff (like http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/), and detailed writeups of microarchitectures (Agner Fog's guides).

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly. So when I run an executable I've written in assembly the OS feeds the CPU my program and also the ranges in absolute memory where I can access? From there on the CPU takes care of it, and in case there is a problem it signals the process?

Comment: It doesn't matter what language you wrote your program in; once it is compiled, it's just machine code.  When you call `exec()`, the compiled file instructs the OS to place the executable code in (virtual) memory and to allow access to execute it.  If you've reserved storage for variables and/or constants, that's indicated in the executable, too.  You might request more memory at runtime (C++ users will use `new` or `malloc`), and if the kernel is willing, it will add more accessible memory to your process.  So the CPU and OS **work together** to manage your process's memory.

Answer (score 2):

A long list of things could go wrong if you jump to an arbitrary location:

Assuming for the moment you are not on a system logical memory translation, things that might happen:

1. The memory location does not exist.
2. The memory location is not correctly aligned for an instruction (some processors)
3. The memory location does not contain a valid instruction.

If you are on a system with logical memory translation:

1. The memory location has no page table entry.
2. The memory location has a page table entry marked invalid.
3. The page table entry is marked no execute.
4. The page table entry is marked as having a more privilege access mode.
5. The memory location identifies an instruction that attempts access memory that causes any of the above.
6. The memory location is a privileged instruction that cannot be executed in the current access mode.

Any of the above will trigger either a fault or trap.